# SQLite: no such module: fts5 error with System.Data.SQLite.dll 1.0.101.0

Tags: .net, sqlite, full-text-search, system.data.sqlite, fts5

I am using System.Data.SQLite.dll 1.0.101.0 and I get this error when execute the command "CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE tbl_fts USING fts5 (fld1, fld2)".

error:
no such module: fts5

in this page we can see: 1.0.99.0 - December 9, 2015

•Add experimental support for the native json1 and fts5 extensions

https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/news.wiki

so what is the problem, and how can I enable fts5, should I rebuild System.Data.SQLite.dll? how can I do that?

thanks..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

here the solution, more than 6 hours of work until found it:

```
    MyConnection.EnableExtensions(True)
    MyConnection.LoadExtension("System.Data.SQLite.dll", "sqlite3_fts5_init") ''/// Or "SQLite.Interop.dll" as you need.
```

I understood that by this sentence: "Add experimental support for the FTS5 loadable extension. (user: mistachkin)"

http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/finfo?name=SQLite.Interop/SQLite.Interop.2010.vcxproj

Comment: I only get a '...procedure not found'. Are you sure that this works for the actual SQLite v1.0.103?

Comment: Yes I tested it with v1.0.103 with no problem. that error because you are using "System.Data.SQLite.dll" but you need to use "SQLite.Interop.dll" if not using 'static-binary-bundle' package. Also note that code must be after MyConnection.Open().

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to call this from a .NET Core 2.1 project.

I didn't manage to get this working using `System.Data.SQLite.dll` so instead I referenced `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.dll` (version 5.0.11). Since this is the package used by EntityFramework Core which does support FTS5.

Note when adding `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite` via NuGet that you need the package with that name and **not** `Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.Core` which does not include the native libraries needed for SQLite.